# Having trouble switching activities

Tags: android

I have two activities: a menu, and a game. I have them both set up as surface views, and when I click the "start" button on the menu activity, it starts the game activity. Then I want it to save the score and return to the menu activity when the player crashes. Both activities have separate threads that start with the activity, so when I tried to re-launch the menu activity from the game, I was getting an exception that the thread was already started. So to avoid this, I had the game activity finish the menu activity when it started so that relaunching the menu activity would also restart the thread. Now I'm getting an exception that the canvas is already locked. Do I need to unlock the canvas before finishing the activity? And is there a better way for me to handle switching between activities?

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.mikey.******;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = this;
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}
```

**GamePanel Layout:**

```
package com.mikey.*****;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static SharedPreferences prefs;
    public static int width;
    public static int height;
    public static int screenX, screenY;
    private Canvas c;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;
    private Scoreboard sb;
    public int moveSpeed = 10;
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
    private Plunger plunger;
    private Plunger plunger1;
    private long smokeStart;
    private long smokeTime;
    public int score = 0;
    public boolean isPlaying;
    private Bitmap bgImg;
    private Bitmap b;
    private int scaleFactor = 2;
    private long timer;
    private long timeStart;
    private Paint paint;
    private ArrayList<Coin> coin;
    private long coinTime;
    private int coinDelay;
    private Bitmap coinImg;
    public boolean playable;
    public int distance;
    private int plungerDelay;
    private int plungerReset;
    private long plungerTime;
    private int coinSet;
    private Menu endMenu;


    public GamePanel(Context context){
        super(context);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenX=size.x;
        screenY=size.y;

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        boolean retry = true;
        int count = 0;
        while(retry&&count<1000){
            try{thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
                retry=false;

            }catch(InterruptedException e){}

            count++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){

        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
        //moveSpeed = -20;

        bgImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg2);
        width = bgImg.getWidth();
        height = bgImg.getHeight();
        bg = new Background(bgImg);
        sb = new Scoreboard(getContext());
        plunger = new Plunger(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plunger));
        plunger1 = new Plunger(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.plunger));
        player = new Player(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.potty));
        smoke = new ArrayList<Smokepuff>();
        coin = new ArrayList<Coin>();
        //Random r = new Random();
        coinImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.coin2);
        coin.add(new Coin(coinImg));
        coinDelay = 5;
        playable = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(!isPlaying&&playable){
                isPlaying=true;
                smokeStart = System.nanoTime();
                timeStart = System.nanoTime();
                plungerReset = distance;
                plungerDelay = 100;
                coinSet = distance;
            }
            player.setAccelerate(true);
            player.setUp(true);
            return true;
        }
        else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            player.setAccelerate(false);
            player.setUp(false);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    public void update(){
        if(isPlaying) {

            timer = (System.nanoTime() - timeStart) / 1000000;
            distance+=(timer*moveSpeed)/1000;

            if (timer > 50) {
                if(player.getAccelerate()&&!player.maxAlt) {
                    moveSpeed += 1;
                }else if(!player.getAccelerate()&&!player.maxAlt){
                    if(moveSpeed>0){
                        if(distance<200){
                            moveSpeed-=.05;
                        }else {
                            moveSpeed -= .18;
                        }
                    }
                }
                timeStart = System.nanoTime();
            }
            //moveSpeed += score;

            smokeTime = (System.nanoTime()-smokeStart)/1000000;
            if(smokeTime>100){
                smoke.add(new Smokepuff(player.getX(),player.getY()+5));
                smokeStart=System.nanoTime();
            }

            if(distance>300&&plungerDelay+plungerReset<distance){
                plunger.setX(screenX);
                plunger1.setX(screenX+500);

                Random q = new Random();
                plungerDelay = q.nextInt(150)+100;
                plungerReset = distance;
            }

            if(distance-coinSet>coinDelay) {
                Random z = new Random();
                int num = z.nextInt(3) + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    coin.add(new Coin(coinImg));
                }
                Random r = new Random();
                coinDelay = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
                coinSet=distance;
            }


            plunger.update(moveSpeed);
            plunger1.update(moveSpeed);
            int dy = player.update();

            bg.update(moveSpeed, dy);




            for(int i=0;i<coin.size();i++){
                coin.get(i).update(moveSpeed);
                if(coin.get(i).getX()<-10){
                    coin.remove(i);
                }else if (collision(coin.get(i), player)) {
                    coin.remove(i);
                    score+=10;
                }
            }

            if(collision(player,plunger)){
                plunger.setX(player.getX() + player.getWidth() - 1);
                plunger.setY(player.getY()+player.height/2);
                if(!plunger.attached){
                    plungerTime = System.nanoTime();
                    plunger.attached = true;
                }
                if(moveSpeed>10){
                    moveSpeed--;
                }
            }
            if(plunger.getX()<-100){
                plunger.reset();
            }

            if(collision(player,plunger1)){
                plunger1.setX(player.getX() + player.getWidth()-1);
                plunger1.setY(player.getY()+player.height/2);
                if(!plunger1.attached) {
                    plungerTime = System.nanoTime();
                    plunger1.attached=true;
                }
                if(moveSpeed>10){
                    moveSpeed--;
                }
            }
            if(plunger1.getX()<-100){
                plunger1.reset();
            }

            if((System.nanoTime()-plungerTime)/1000000>750){
                if(collision(plunger,player)){
                    plunger.reset();
                    plunger.attached = false;
                }
                if(collision(plunger1,player)){
                    plunger1.reset();
                    plunger1.attached = false;
                }
            }

            for(int i=0;i<smoke.size();i++){
                smoke.get(i).update(moveSpeed);
                if(smoke.get(i).getX()<-10||smoke.get(i).getY()<0){
                    smoke.remove(i);
                }
            }

            sb.update(score, distance);

            if(2*player.getY()>screenY-300){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                if(!prefs.contains("highscore")) {
                    editor.putInt("highscore", score);
                    //return;
                }else if(prefs.getInt("highscore",0)<score){
                    editor.putInt("highscore",score);
                }
                editor.commit();

                isPlaying=false;
                playable=false;
                endGame();
                //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(MainActivity.activity);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Menu.class);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    }

    public boolean collision(GameObject a, GameObject b){
        if(Rect.intersects(a.getRect(),b.getRect())){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

        final float scaleFactorX = (float) 2;
        final float scaleFactorY = (float) 2;

        if(canvas!=null){
            c = canvas;

            final int savedState = canvas.save();
            canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
            bg.draw(canvas);
            for(Coin c:coin){
                c.draw(canvas);
            }
            plunger.draw(canvas);
            plunger1.draw(canvas);
            for(Smokepuff sp:smoke){
                sp.draw(canvas);
            }
            player.draw(canvas);
            if((isPlaying&&playable)||(!isPlaying&&!playable)) {
                sb.draw(canvas);
            }
            canvas.restoreToCount(savedState);
            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(moveSpeed), screenX-100,40,paint);
        }
        //bg.draw(canvas);

    }

    public void endGame(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        if(!prefs.contains("highscore")) {
            editor.putInt("highscore", score);
            return;
        }else if(prefs.getInt("highscore",0)<score){
            editor.putInt("highscore",score);
        }
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Menu.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**Menu Activity:**

```
package com.mikey.*****;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Menu extends Activity{

    //private ImageButton upgrade;
    private int screenY;
    private int screenX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        screenY = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
        screenX = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
        setContentView(new MenuLayout(this));
        /*upgrade = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.upgrade);
        upgrade.setX(-150);
        upgrade.setY(1080-130);
        upgrade.setScaleX(4);
        upgrade.setScaleY(4);*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

**MenuLayout:**

```
package com.mikey.*****;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.RadialGradient;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MenuLayout extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static SharedPreferences prefs;
    private MenuThread thread;
    private boolean played;
    private int screenX, screenY;
    private Bitmap upgrade;
    private Bitmap map;
    private Bitmap bg;
    private Bitmap launch;
    private Bitmap potty;
    private Bitmap cloudA;
    private Bitmap cloudB;
    private ArrayList<Cloud> cloud;
    private UpgradeBtn upgradeBtn;
    private MapBtn mapBtn;
    private LaunchBtn launchBtn;
    //private Paint bg;
    private Paint feature;
    private Paint border;
    private Paint featureRad;
    private Paint stick;
    private Paint text;
    private Paint shadow;

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private boolean upg;
    private boolean showmap;
    private boolean start;

    public MenuLayout(Context context){
        super(context);

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        thread = new MenuThread(getHolder(),this);
        setFocusable(true);


        screenX=size.x;
        screenY=size.y;

        upgrade = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.blueprint);
        map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.map);
        launch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.launch);
        bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.menu_bg);
        potty = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.potty1);
        cloudA = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cloud1);
        cloudB = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cloud2);

        upgradeBtn = new UpgradeBtn(upgrade,screenY);
        mapBtn = new MapBtn(map);
        launchBtn = new LaunchBtn(launch,screenX,screenY);

        cloud = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
            addCloud();
        }
        start = true;

        //bg = new Paint();
        //bg.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        shadow = new Paint();
        shadow.setAntiAlias(true);
        shadow.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        shadow.setTextSize(45.0f);
        shadow.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
        shadow.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        shadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f, Color.BLACK);

        Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 90, Color.LTGRAY, Color.DKGRAY, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        feature = new Paint();
        feature.setShader(shader);

        border = new Paint();
        border.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        border.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        border.setStrokeWidth(8);

        Shader shader1 = new RadialGradient(screenX-60,60,150,Color.LTGRAY,Color.DKGRAY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
        featureRad = new Paint();
        featureRad.setShader(shader1);

        stick = new Paint();
        stick.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        stick.setStrokeWidth(20);

        text = new Paint();
        text.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        text.setTextSize(50);
    }

    public void addCloud(){

        Bitmap img;
        Random r = new Random();
        Random p = new Random();
        Random q = new Random();

        int s = r.nextInt(10);
        if(s>5){
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            float h = r.nextFloat()+1;
            m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, cloudA.getWidth(), cloudA.getHeight()),
                    new RectF(0, 0, cloudA.getWidth()*h, cloudA.getHeight()*h), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            img = Bitmap.createBitmap(cloudA, 0, 0, cloudA.getWidth(), cloudA.getHeight(), m, true);
        }else{
            img = cloudB;
        }
        if(start){
            x = -img.getWidth();
        }
        else{
            x = p.nextInt(screenX);
        }

        cloud.add(new Cloud(img,x,p.nextInt(screenY-750)+100,q.nextInt(8)+1,screenX));

    }

    public Bitmap highlightImage(Bitmap src, int color,boolean x, boolean y) {
        int xMod;
        int yMod;
        if(x){
           xMod = 4;
        }else{
            xMod = -1;
        }
        if(y){
            yMod = 2;
        }
        else{
            yMod = -1;
        }
        // create new bitmap, which will be painted and becomes result image
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth()*5/4+30, src.getHeight()*5/4+30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // setup canvas for painting
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOut);
        canvas.scale(1.25f,1.25f);

        // setup default color
        canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        // create a blur paint for capturing alpha
        Paint ptBlur = new Paint();
        ptBlur.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
        int[] offsetXY = new int[2];
        // capture alpha into a bitmap
        Bitmap bmAlpha = src.extractAlpha(ptBlur, offsetXY);
        // create a color paint
        Paint ptAlphaColor = new Paint();
        ptAlphaColor.setColor(color);
        // paint color for captured alpha region (bitmap)
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmAlpha, xMod*offsetXY[0]/2, yMod*offsetXY[1], ptAlphaColor);
        // free memory
        bmAlpha.recycle();

        // paint the image source
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

        // return out final image
        return bmOut;
    }

    public void launchUpgrade(){
        upg = true;
        upgradeBtn.setImg(upgrade);
    }

    public void launchMap(){
        showmap = true;
        mapBtn.setImg(map);
    }

    public void launchProfile(){

    }

    public void startGame(){
        launchBtn.setImg(launch);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
        getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(!thread.getRunning()) {
            thread.setRunning(true);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        boolean retry = true;
        int count = 0;
        if(thread.getRunning()) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
        /*while(retry&&count<1000){
            try{thread.setRunning(false);
                thread.join();
                retry=false;

            }catch(InterruptedException e){}

            count++;
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        x =(int) event.getX();
        y =(int) event.getY();

        if (x < 710 && y > 780) {
            upgradeBtn.setImg(highlightImage(upgrade,Color.BLUE,false,true));
        }else{
            upgradeBtn.setImg(upgrade);
        }
        if (x < 520 && y < 275) {
            mapBtn.setImg(highlightImage(map,Color.YELLOW,true,false));
        }else{
            mapBtn.setImg(map);
        }
        if(x>1500&&y>700){
            launchBtn.setImg(highlightImage(launch,Color.RED,true,true));
        }else{
            launchBtn.setImg(launch);
        }


        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (x < 710 && y > 780) {
                launchUpgrade();
                return true;
            }

            if (x < 520 && y < 275) {
                launchMap();
                return true;
            }

            if(x>1700&&y<235){
                launchProfile();
                return true;
            }
            if(x>1500&&y>700){
                startGame();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void update(){

        for(int i=0;i<cloud.size();i++){
            cloud.get(i).update();
            if(cloud.get(i).getX()>screenX){
                cloud.remove(i);
                addCloud();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas){

        if(canvas!=null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bg,-3,0,null);
            for(int i=0;i<cloud.size();i++){
                cloud.get(i).draw(canvas);
            }
            canvas.drawBitmap(potty, screenX / 2 - 190, screenY / 2 - 190, null);
            //canvas.drawBitmap(upgrade, -235, screenY - upgrade.getHeight() + 300, null);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(screenX - 550, 5, screenX - 150, 105, 15, 15, feature);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(screenX - 550, 5, screenX - 150, 105, 25, 25, border);
            canvas.drawCircle(screenX - 60, 60, 150, featureRad);
            canvas.drawCircle(screenX - 60, 60, 150, border);
            canvas.drawCircle(screenX / 2 + 230, screenY / 2 + 110, 50, stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX / 2 + 220, screenY / 2 + 110, screenX / 2 + 185, screenY / 2 + 340, stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX / 2 + 185, screenY / 2 + 340, screenX / 2 + 270, screenY/2+440,stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX/2+270,screenY/2+440,screenX/2+270,screenY,stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX/2+270,screenY/2+440,screenX/2+340,screenY,stick);
            canvas.drawLine(((screenX / 2 + 220)+(screenX / 2 + 185))/2,screenY/2+230,screenX/2+210,
                    screenY/2+250,stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX/2+185,screenY/2+250,screenX/2+245,screenY/2+235,stick);
            canvas.drawLine(screenX / 2 + 235, screenY / 2 + 245, ((screenX / 2 + 220) + (screenX / 2 + 185)) / 2,
                    screenY / 2 + 230, stick);

            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(prefs.getInt("highscore", 0)), 1000, 50, text);

            upgradeBtn.draw(canvas);
            mapBtn.draw(canvas);
            launchBtn.draw(canvas);

            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(x)+","+Integer.toString(y),50,50,text);

            /*if(upg){
                canvas.drawText("UPGRADE",540,400,text);
                canvas.drawBitmap(highlightImage(upgrade), -235, screenY - upgrade.getHeight() + 300,null);
            }*/
            if(showmap){
                canvas.drawText("MAP",540,500,text);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I'm sure there is a lot more wrong with my code than just the issue I'm having because I'm very new to this, so if you have any general suggestions to clean up my code, I'd love to hear those as well.

Comment: Please show your code for MenuActivity, Game Activity and Logcat,so that we can debug it.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid I hope that is useful. The intents are in the GamePanel and MenuLayout code